# how to solve error linear equation system

Tags: equation-solving

I can't run the code below because there is some error. How to solve the "null" problem and show answers exactly with convergence.
The code following:

```
(*Program EQUIL to solve the 3 layer equilibrium height problem.The \indefinite integral and the 
limits at+1,-1 have been obtained \from:fd:Integrate[(cO+c1*y)*Sqrt[(1-y)/(1+y)l,yl 
\fu:Integrate[(cO+c1*y)*Sqrt[(1+y)/(1-y)l,Yl but now only the final \results are used:*)

fd[y_, cO_,c1_] := ((1 - y)/(1 + y))^(1/2)*(cO - c1 + ((2*cO - c1)*y)/2 + (c1*y^2)/2) - (2*cO - c1)*
ArcTan[y*((1 - y)/(1 + y))^(1/2)/(-1 + y)]/2 
fu[y_, cO_, c1_ ] := ((-1 - y)/(-1 + y))^(1/2)*(-cO - c1 + ((2*cO + c1)*y)/2 + (c1*y^2)/2) + (2*cO + 
c1)*
ArcTan[y*((-1 - y)/(-1 + y))^(1/2)/(1 + y)]/2 
fup1[cO_, c1_] := Pi/4*(2*cO + c1) 
fum1[cO_, c1_] := Pi/4*(-2*cO - c1) 
fdp1[cO_, c1_] := Pi/4*(2*cO - c1)
  fdm1[cO_, c1_] := Pi/4*(-2*cO + c1)
(*compute stress intensities'upward' and'downward'*) 
 subs = {
  hh -> hp + dhd + dhu,
 yd -> -1 + 2 dhd/(hp + dhd + dhu),
yu -> 1 - 2 dhu/(hp + dhd + dhu),
cOO -> sigma + dp + rho*g*(dhd - dhu)/2,
   c1 -> -rho*g*(hp + dhd + dhu)/2} 
   Ku = Sqrt[ hh/(2*Pi)] + (fu[yd, cOO - sigmad, c1] - fum1[cOO - sigmad, c1] +  fu[yu, cOO - sigma, 
 c1] - fu[yd, cOO - sigma, c1] + fup1[cOO - sigmau, c1] - fu[yu, cOO - sigmau, c1]) /. subs
 KKd = Sqrt[ hh/(2*Pi)]*(fd[yd, cOO - sigmad, c1] - fdm1[cOO - sigmad, c1] +  fd[yu, cOO - sigma, c1] 
- fd[yd, cOO - sigma, c1] + fdp1[cOO - sigmau, c1] - fd[yu, cOO - sigmau, c1]) /. subs
 (*Format and Messages*)
 p1[x_] := PaddedForm[N[x], {6, 1}] Off[FindRoot::cvnwt] Off[FindRoot::frmp]
 (*unit conversion constants and acceleration of gravity*)
  psi = 6.894757 *10 ^3
   ft = 0.3048 
  lbmpft3 = 16.01846 
    inch = 0.0254 
  psisqin = psi *Sqrt[inch]
   g = 9.81
  (*Problem specific data*) 
   KICtop = 1000*psisqin 
  KICbot = 1000 *psisqin 
  sigma = 4500*psi 
   hp = 60*ft 
  sigmau = 5100 *psi 
  sigmad = 5300*psi 
  rho = 55*lbmpft3
  (*Headings*)
  Print["           dp        dhu      dhd        Ku            KKd"]
  Print["           psi       ft       ft        psi*in^0.5    psi*in^0.5"]
  (*
   Solve the two simultaneous equations using different starting points \
   Print the height migrations Check the calculated stress intensity \
   factors
   *) 
  Do[
   r1 = FindRoot[{KICtop == Ku, KICbot == KKd}, {dhu, 10 ft}, {dhd, 
    10 ft}];
  wr = SequenceForm[p1[dp/psi], p1[dhu/ft], p1[dhd/ft], p1[Ku/psisqin],
    p1[KKd/psisqin]] /. r1;
  If[(N[Abs[KICtop - Ku /. r1] + Abs[KICbot - KKd /. r1]] > 0.1), 
  Break[],];
   r2 = FindRoot[{KICtop == Ku, KICbot == KKd}, {dhu, 10 ft}, {dhd, 
   1000 ft}];
    If[(N[Abs[KICtop - Ku /. r2] + Abs[KICbot - KKd /. r2]] < 
    0.1 psisqin) && (dhd /. r2) > 0 && (dhu /. r2) > 
   0 && (Abs[(dhd /. r2) - (dhd /. r1)] > 0.1*ft), 
    wr = SequenceForm[w, p1[dhu/ft], p1[dhd/ft], p1[Ku/psisqin], 
     p1[KKd/psisqin]] /. r2 ];
   Print[wr], {dp, 100 psi, 700 psi, 50 psi} ]
```

when I run the code ... it has the error

FindRoot::: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.